# How much computing time does the kernel need

Tags: esp8266

I wrote a program for a LED display. The program allows to set the refresh rate via webconfiguration. To meet the refresh rate I measure the processing time of a loop. At the end I calculate the delay and wait until the next loop.

e.g. Refresh Rate 5 Hz -> 200 milli seconds for one loop. 50 milli seconds computing time results in 150 milli seconds delay.

The ratio of process time (50 milli seconds) to total time (200 milli seconds) indicates the processor load of my program. But to find the optimal setting, I need the actual total processor load. And not only that of my program. But since I don't know the real processor load of the delay() (in which WIFI etc. is done), I don't really know the processor load. In other words, I don't know how much time the system spends doing system tasks in the delay(150).

Is there a way to find out how much of a delay is actually used for system tasks before the processor truly waits?

In other words, I'm looking for a way to get the kernel time within a certain time frame.

Cheers Gabriel

Comment: is it Arduino? use timing with millis() function

Comment: "how much of a delay is actually used for system tasks before the processor truly waits?" - that is certainly not consistent enough to be used in any algorithm.

Comment: Of course it makes sense. Of course, you have to look at it in a certain time frame. Otherwise it makes no sense. Otherwise you could not calculate the performance of a processor. This should be clear to the reader who answers this advanced question. 

That's why I was talking about a tacked application. 

The calculation is trivial. Let's consider an application that runs with one Herz. That means, the loop must be run through once a second. How do you do that? Measure the own process time. Calculate the remaining time.....

Comment: And wait until the second is over. And here my thing comes into play. I'll probably create a feature request in Github. Because there seems to be nothing. The solution is simple.

1. remember start time
2. run own programs
3. remember endtime
4. delay(1000 - (endtime-starttime)) // here for the sake of simplicity in millisec

-> 
process runtime: (endtime-starttime)
wait time+kernel time; 1000-(endtime-starttime)

Comment: Within the delay the kernel works on e.g.  Serial.print, WiFi (at EPS) and so on. What you need is also trivial:

1. remember starttime & remember kerneltime
2. execute own programs
3. remember endtime.
4. delay
5. remember kernel time and calculate the difference to the last query.

This would give you the kernel runtime within a known timeframe and the rutime of your own code:  And with this you can calculate the load like with a large processor. The load the 

computing time in total + real waiting time = time frame

total computing time in % + idle time in % = 100 %.

Comment: It is a common misconception that the utilization of a microprocessor is always 100%.Of course not!!!!! It depends on the program.  A program that is calculated in a loop constantly without waiting something is utilization 100%. That is clear. But as soon as the whole thing is tacked and runs asyncron, it is different. What people often do not understand is that the utilization is always to be seen in a time frame. And a microprocessor is in no way different from a desktop processor. Only that the latter has more power and often more cores. All processors are linear.